# Entity Framework set the ID into specific value

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

Good Day!

I just want to ask how can I set the ID into specific value for example the ID would start at 10 then the next value when incremented value would be 11. Please help me, thanks in advance.

```
 Public Function GetNewNumber(ByVal deptid As Integer) As Integer
        Dim retval As Integer

        Try
            retval = (From prD As PRInfo In PRCTX.PRInfo s Where prD.dID = deptid Select prD.prID).Count + 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            retval = 0
            Me.AddError("Error: Get New  Number where Dept. ID is " & deptid & ": " & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return retval
    End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you use identity seed?

Comment: @GertArnold, the thing this is not a primary key from the database for example the One I'm pointing in the code above "pNumber" in generates an ID by Department in one Column.

Comment: Can you use SQL2012 sequences? What you're doing is not concurrency-safe. Apart from that, making sure that the function only returns a value >= 10 shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @GertArnold there are existing data in the database if I would do that the data will got affected.